# How to append i'th element of a list to first entry in i'th list in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, append

That is: each element in a list ends up as the first element in the corresponding list in a list of lists.

Like the following:

```
List_of_Lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,4,4]]
List1 = [1,2,3]
```

Resulting:

```
New_List_of_List = [[1,1,2,3][2,2,3,4],[3,4,4,4]]
```

I have tried various append and insert methods, but the main problem is that I'm not sure how to mash up individual lists in List_of_Lists and elements in List.

Comment: The question you have formed is 90% the answer itself. It's just in word format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the elements at the 0 position

```
lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,4,4]]
List1 = [1,2,3]
for i in range(len(lists)):
    
     lists[i].insert(0,List1[i])
print(lists)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
List_of_Lists = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
List1 = [1, 2, 3]

out = [[v, *subl] for v, subl in zip(List1, List_of_Lists)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[1, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for idx, sub_list in enumerate(List_of_Lists):
    sub_list.insert(0, List1[idx])
```

> The above code will modify your List_of_Lists, if you don't want that please create a copy and then loop through the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code I wrote to insert a value anywhere in sub-lists.

```
import copy
List_of_Lists = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,4,4]]
List1 = ['Z','Y','X']

def Insert_List_of_Lists(List_X,index,value):
    temp_list=copy.deepcopy(List_X)
    if index<=len(temp_list):
       for i in range(len(temp_list)):
           temp_list[i].insert(index,value)
    else:
       for i in range(len(temp_list)):
           temp_list[i].insert(len(temp_list),value)
       print("Given index Out of range, value appended")
    return(temp_list)

New_List_of_List = Insert_List_of_Lists(List_of_Lists,3,List1[0])
New_List_of_List
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 'Z'], [2, 3, 4, 'Z'], [4, 4, 4, 'Z']]
```

When we try to add a value out of index:

```
X_list = Insert_List_of_Lists(List_of_Lists,8,'J')
X_list
```

Output:

```
Given index Out of range, value appended
[[1, 2, 3, 'J'], [2, 3, 4, 'J'], [4, 4, 4, 'J']]
```