# writing data of two lists to a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

`c=[[1,2,3],[4,5,2]]`

`b=[4,8]`

How can I write the lists to a text file in the below way?

```
4,1,2,3
8,4,5,2
```

So far I've tried

```
with open("out.txt", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(zip(b,c))
```

But the output is not as I desired.

```
4,"[1, 2, 3]"
8,"[4, 5, 2]"
9,"[2, 3, 1]"
```

[I have found a suggestion for combining these lists, but is there another way other than the list manipulation suggested in this reply?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67834414/16929904)

Comment: No, the method shown in the post you linked is the ideal way to combine those lists in the fashion you want. Why are you opposed to using `[[x, *y] for x, y in zip(b, c)]`?

Comment: I have no objection to that method, but with my crude understanding of python, I was naively wondering if there was an option in the ```csv.writer```. Thank you!